# Angle of deviation in a prism given ONLY the prism angle

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, geometric-optics, geometry

This is **NOT** about calculating the minimum deviation of a prism. You are given only two pieces of information: the angle of the prism, the refractive index of the medium (glass), and you know that the input ray is horizontal (parallel to the base of the prism). The refractive index of the entry material is air, so refractive index is unity. Is it possible to derive the deviation of the beam in terms of prism angle *without* knowing the exact angle of incidence? I have been on a whiteboard scratching my head trying to derive this one...

Comment: If you know the angle of the prism, and that the incident ray is parallel to the base, that tells you the angle of incidence. It's just geometry.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow - The angle of incidence is measured normal to the material, so I am unsure how you could go from prism angle -> incidence

Comment: Is the prism cross-section at least an isosceles triangle?

Comment: @DJohnM No - consider it unknown

Comment: This kind of optical prisms are always isosceles. If its not, there is not enough information for this problem.

Comment: @Ryanator13, not sure if you saw my comment. However the other answers are correct, and if it is an arbitrary triangle, then the problem is undefined, because all you know from this problem is a single angle (one of the internal triangle angles). That the incident light is parallel to the base is useless if the base can be anything...its like me saying "the ray (a laser) comes from my kitchen...now calculate"

Comment: You guys are absolutely correct. My prof got back and said that he forgot to mention that...you guys are awesome, sorry for overcomplicating the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Geometry]

Draw the perpendicular. The angles shown as $a$ are all equal

Comment: did you draw the diagram? if yes, what website or app did you use pls?

Comment: Thank you for drawing this out - been a minute since I have done trig, and another set of eyes always helps, so I appreciate it!

Comment: @ChristinaMelita   I drew it using R.

Comment: Does this assume that the prism equilateral or isosceles? Because if it were scalene, it is not necessarily true that the normal line bisects the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hints:  Line AB is straight, EDC is 90 degrees, CDB can be found in terms of $\theta$, so ADE can be got in terms of $\theta$ and that's the angle of incidence you need.

Comment: This leaves CBD as an unknown - it is not for certain an isosceles triangle

Comment: Either the question you were given has different answers depending on CBD (in that case it's impossible to do) or the same answer as CBD varies - and in that case you can assume it's an isosceles triangle and get the answer.